Azure devops pipeline build failing with MSB4062 Error
Azure devops pipeline Android build is failing with the error

##[error]C:\Users$csadoeagent001.nuget\packages\mobile.buildtools\2.0.245\build\Mobile.BuildTools.targets(37,5): Error MSB4062: The "Mobile.BuildTools.Tasks.LocateBuildToolsConfigTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users%24csadoeagent001.nuget\packages\mobile.buildtools\2.0.245\build\Mobile.BuildTools.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users%24csadoeagent001.nuget\packages\mobile.buildtools\2.0.245\build\Mobile.BuildTools.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

This works fine in local and also works when I use azure hosted agents (windows-2022 and windows-latest). I'm trying to configure Sonarqube to this build hence I have updated the build to use self hosted windows agent. It is failing while building the unit tests.
I tried:

updating the NuGetToolInstaller@0 to NuGetToolInstaller@1
updating the nuget tool version to 5.8.0 to 6.10.0
updating the .net core sdk from 7.0.306 to 8.0.205 and 8.0.206,
updating the mobile.buildtools version 2.0.190-pre to 2.0.245.

No change in the error.

According to your description, it works in local but fails using self-hosted agent. Is the machine where your self-hosted agent is located the same machine as the local machine you mentioned? If not, please set up a self-hosted agent on your working local machine and check if it works. Based on the current info, it seems to be related to your self-hosted agent's environment.

No. It was the developer who tested it locally and confirmed it to be working. As it is working successfully when I use the azure hosted (windows-latest) agent, I have updated our self-hosted agent with the same specifications similar to the azure hosted agent but no luck.

Your pipeline works when using the MS-hosted agent, so we can know the pipeline and your project don't have any issue. It's related to the environment of your self-hosted agent. You can set up a self-hosted agent on the machine which your developer has used. It should work. You need to compare the differences between two machines.
